# Neo4j Cypher Pattern comprehension in return statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to add to my Cypher query's return statement the following  Pattern comprehension:

```
[ (rc:Criterion) WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds | {entity: rc} ] AS decisionReplaceableCriteria
```

but it fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input 'WHERE': expected "-", "<", <ARROW_LEFT_HEAD> or <ARROW_LINE>
```

It only works when I'm adding the redundant relationship with another node

```
[ (rc:Criterion)-[:CREATED_BY]->(:User) WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds | {entity: rc} ] AS decisionReplaceableCriteria
```

The following part is absolutely redundant for my needs:

```
-[:CREATED_BY]->(:User)
```

Is it possible to rewrite my pattern comprehension to avoid such redundant syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Neo4j 5.6+, you can use the [COLLECT subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#collect-subqueries). Here is a sample snippet:

```
...
RETURN COLLECT {
    MATCH (rc:Criterion)
    WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds
    RETURN {entity: rc}
} AS decisionReplaceableCriteria
```

In prior versions of Neo4j, you can try a hack:

```
...
RETURN [ (rc:Criterion)-[*0]->() WHERE rc.id IN childD.replaceableCriterionIds | {entity: rc} ] AS decisionReplaceableCriteria
```

This uses a [variable-length path](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/primer/#variable-length-paths) pattern specifying a length of 0. If you want to see if this variable-length path pattern causes any DB hits, [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/query-profile/) your query and look at the `VarLengthExpand` operation's "db hits".

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm on 5.5 right now

Comment: See my updated answer for a suggestion.